# Install anonymous proxy on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

How to install an anonymous proxy in Ubuntu 9.10 server which listens on every public network ethernet interfaces?

I have other service like Nginx, MySQL running on that server so I hope the proxy server wont conflict with them.

**EDIT**

I just wanted to browse web pages via the proxy I setup on my server while hide my origining ip addresses. It's not for public use but i connect to the proxy from my home computer, etc.

Anonymous mean it does not carry a "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR" field in HTTP request header.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by anonymous, and are the people you want to serve on your local network or coming from the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/).  There should be an Ubuntu package for it, and it's not hard to set up.  You can configure it to not send headers with your original IP.

Answer (score 0):

it is nothing do with mysql as well nginx